# Can i execute multiple sql server queries in a mvc controller and display the results in single view in a MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

Right now I have a controller which executes a single query and displays it in the view. I want to execute another query where I get the number of records based on a filter. Can I do this in the same view?

This is my current controller class:

```
public class AutoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Auto
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var entities = new ticketsEntities();

        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(entities.Tickets.OrderByDescending(Tickets=>Tickets.TicketCreation).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt edit the code properly. return View(entities.Tickets.OrderByDescending(Tickets=>Tickets.TicketCreation).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));

Comment: You can use partial views for rendering multiple/different results: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/best-way-to-bind-partial-views-for-improving-performance/

Comment: Yes, there's nothing stopping you from doing that.

Comment: On a side note change `Index(int? page)` to `Index(int page = 1)` to set a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

1. Use ViewBag

///////

```
//In controller
ViewBag["Total"] = entities.Tickets.Count();


//In View
<p>@ViewBag["Total"]</p>
```

2. Use Custom View Model

Yes, you can create a new model class, populate it and pass it to the view.

e.g.

```
public class MyCustomModel
{
   public IPagedList<Tickets> Tickets {get;set;}
   public long Total {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller:

```
MyCustomModel mymodel = new MyCustomModel();
mymodel.Total = entities.Tickets.Count();
mymodel.Tickets = entities.Tickets.OrderByDescending(Tickets=>Tickets.TicketCreation).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5)

return View(mymodel);
```

Then in your view you can set the model as:

```
@model MyCustomModel

<p>Model.Total</p>
```

Comment: I already have  a IPagedList Model. i just want to run another query to count the number of records and display in the view.

Comment: @Hari Updated my answer